# Can this question about ice be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, reopen

[Can ice freeze?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163574/can-ice-freeze)

I think this question is about explaining physical laws and physical chemistry and  also related to "Accepted and/or actively researched theories" which are on-topic. I believe I gave enough details also.

It was put on hold after a long time and after I got a good answer that I was willing to accept but I was waiting for a while if I can get any other good answers.

This was the reason to put on-hold:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Based on this, I also added "further clarification" section. I can clarify further if it is needed but one of the aims of the question is getting a clarification also. There are also related questions, it is not only one question. The question is, of course, asking for a detailed, well-documented answer which I got also.

Can it be re-opened please?

Answer (score 3):

I still think the question, as posed:

> In the end, can we say that different crystalline forms have different solid states? Can ice freeze further by transforming into a different crystalline form?

is unclear. You demonstrate that you are aware of the possibility of different crystal lattices (hexagonal vs. cubic ice is your example), which consequently have different material properties. But then you ask whether ice "freezes further", and what is happening when it does so, as if you were *not* aware of different crystal structures.

I really don't get what you're asking.

Comment: The current answer in the question answers it. So someone got it. Though, there can be further details. I'm not aware of the details of material properties in different solid phases.

Comment: The current answer also says that "Freezing means solidifying. That is a word for the transition from liquid→solid. Since that doesn't occour again in between solid phases, "freeze further" has no meaning." As phrased, the question is unclear. If you can readdress it to ask about the different phases of solid water and their different properties - that's another matter. But "freezing further" is not going to make sense no matter how you rephrase it.

Comment: I already gave further clarification. If it cannot be interpreted as freezing, it can be explained as a part of the answer with details. Also, in the current answer, the answerer said that in a solid phase, ice might melt and freeze again without changing the solid state, so it is like a "new" freezing. Obviously there are a lot of details out there to construct a nice answer.

Comment: I think it would help your question to _remove_ use of terms like "freeze further". Be more precise about what you mean throughout the question. The fact that one person was able to correctly guess what you were asking doesn't necessarily mean your question was clear.

Comment: @DavidZ: You can think vice versa also. If it is unclear for a few people, it doesn't mean it is unclear for everyone. Also I considered suggestions already. I included further clarification.

Comment: @ermanen right, but I believe it's unclear for _most_ people, not just a few.